# date conversion formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some dated in this format "09-MAY-13 06.42.46.097127000 PM" and need to convert to this format "2013-05-09T18:42:47.132Z". my goal is to find out which happend earlier. I am not sure how to format these dates.

```
2013-05-09T18:42:47.132Z    09-MAY-13 06.42.46.097127000 PM
2013-05-08T20:56:55.821Z    06-MAY-13 03.22.09.129443000 PM
2013-05-08T20:51:45.287Z    06-MAY-13 03.03.22.975700000 PM
2013-05-08T20:55:34.719Z    06-MAY-13 10.40.55.924181000 PM
```

How I can do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally posted an answer which converted one of your formats to the other. I now see that you need to `compare` them, so you can convert this format in A2 to date/number values ....

**09-MAY-13 06.42.46.097127000 PM**

.....with this formula

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",":",1),".",":",1)+0`

and this format in A3

**2013-05-09T18:42:46.097z**

....with this formula

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"T"," "),"z","")+0`

You can format the results how you like, leave as numbers or format as `m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000` or similar. you can now compare easily with a formula like

`=B2>B3`

or get the smaller or larger with MIN or MAX

Answer (score 0):

If have a value of your original style in cell A1, place the following formula in a different cell:

```
=DATE((2000+MID(A1,8,2)),MATCH(MID(A1,4,3),{"JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"},0),LEFT(A1,2))+TIME(MID(A1,11,2)+IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="PM",12,0),MID(A1,14,2),MID(A1,17,12))
```

Then, in that target cell, apply the following format:

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ
```

Please note the following:

- This assumes that all of your months are 3 characters (JAN, FEB, MAR). Since your example was "MAY" (already 3 characters), I don't know with certainty how your other months appear. Longer month names complicate the formula a bit. I can help with this if you need it and don't know how to do it.
- I couldn't find a way to force Excel to display fractional seconds in the context of such complex date/time formatting, even though your example showed seconds subdivided to the thousandths. Hopefully this isn't a deal-breaker. If it's necessary to display fractional seconds, you may need to handle this with a separate formula to display the result as text, independent of the formula above, which you can use for your calculations of which date came earlier.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Joe's answer...
To get Excel to compare one column to the other you need to do the same sort of manipulation from the first column as the second.

That would look like

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,5))
```

Once you have a new column for each of these transformations it should be simple to have Excel compare them.